# How to differentiate between bulk fields and simple fields?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bloomberg, blpapi

Using python API blpapi to convert excel formulas like BDP and BDS

I need to recognize whether the required field is **Bulk field (for BDS)** or **simple field (for BDP)**

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bulk fields have data type = Datatype.SEQUENCE

```
Element field = fields.GetElement(i);
// Checking if the field is Bulk field
if (field.Datatype == Datatype.SEQUENCE)
{
    processBulkField(field);
}
else
{
    processRefField(field);
}
```

See *BulkRefDataExample.*

Comment: Python:

if (field.datatype() == blpapi.DataType.SEQUENCE)

datatype() documentation: https://bloomberg.github.io/blpapi-docs/python/3.13/_autosummary/blpapi.Element.html#blpapi.Element.datatype